# Conditionally append rows from one dataframe to another based on key-id and date range

Tags: python, pandas, append

I have two large dataframes with the same columns.  Example data of relevance is presented below.

```
import pandas as pd 
    
df1 = [[52, '1', 'Mast', '1/1/2022'], [54, '1', 'Mast', '1/1/2023'],
       [55, '2', 'Mast', '25/5/2022'], [52, '1', 'Mast', '14/7/2022']]
    
df = pd.DataFrame(df1, columns =['Cow','Lact', 'Event', 'Date'])
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d/%m/%Y')


df2 = [[60, '1', 'Other', '10/1/2022'], [54, '1', 'Other', '3/1/2023'],
       [55, '2', 'Other', '30/5/2022'], [52, '1', 'Other', '14/8/2022']]

    
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2, columns =['Cow', 'Lact', 'Event', 'Date'])
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
```

The structure of df is

```
Cow Lact    Event   Date
0   52  1   Mast    2022-01-01
1   54  1   Mast    2023-01-01
2   55  2   Mast    2022-05-25
3   52  1   Mast    2022-07-14
```

The structure of df2 is

```
    Cow Lact    Event   Date
0   60  1   Other   2022-01-10
1   54  1   Other   2023-01-03
2   55  2   Other   2022-05-30
3   52  1   Other   2022-08-14
```

I would like to append rows from df2 to df if the "Cow" and "Lact" from df2 matches df and the "Date" of df2 fits within the range of the "Date" in df and five days greater than the "Date" of df.

The desired output with this example data is

```
Cow Lact    Event   Date
0   52  1   Mast    2022-01-01
1   54  1   Mast    2023-01-01
2   54  1   Other   2023-01-03
3   55  2   Mast    2022-05-25
4   55  2   Other   2022-05-30
5   52  1   Mast    2022-07-14
```

Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a clean solution, but it works:

```py
# create temp columns cow-Lact
df['cow_lact'] = df['Cow'].astype(str) + '_' +  df['Lact'].astype(str)
df2['cow_lact'] = df2['Cow'].astype(str) + '_' +  df2['Lact'].astype(str)

# select correct columns from df2 
df_append = df2[
    df2['cow_lact'].isin(df['cow_lact'])
    & df2['Date'].between(df['Date'].min(), df['Date'].max() + pd.Timedelta(days=5))]

# concat
result = pd.concat([df,df_append], ignore_index=True)
# drop temp column
result.drop(columns=['cow_lact'])
```

Comment: When I use the merge_asof method it takes the next event that meets the criteria.  With the append method it includes all "Other" events that meet the criteria which is what I need. Thank you both.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html#pandas.merge_asof):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'])

keep = pd.merge_asof(
              df[['Cow', 'Lact', 'Date']].sort_values(by='Date'),
              df2.reset_index().sort_values(by='Date'),
              on='Date', by=['Cow', 'Lact'],
              direction='forward',
              tolerance=pd.Timedelta('5D')
             )['index'].dropna()

out = pd.concat([df, df2.loc[keep]])
```

Output:

```
   Cow Lact  Event       Date
0   52    1   Mast 2022-01-01
1   54    1   Mast 2023-01-01
2   55    2   Mast 2022-05-25
3   52    1   Mast 2022-07-14
2   55    2  Other 2022-05-30
1   54    1  Other 2023-01-03
```

Comment: If you want all events from df2 you can perform the `merge_asof` with `df` on the left (this is a left merge). You would need to change the `direction` ;)